# Dynamically create a new folder when uploading images in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I've been playing with multiple files and I've successfully managed how to upload multiple files (in my case images) into the public/storage folder in Laravel, but I want to upgrade the method to dynamically create a folder based on user ID.

In a nutshell, when user select let's say 10 images, hit the submit button, a folder with his ID will be created and then those 10 images will end up in this folder.

This is my function to store the images:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $files = $request->file('file');

        if(!empty($files)):

            foreach($files as $file):
                Storage::disk('photos')->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
            endforeach;

        endif;
    }
```

And the filesystem:

```
'photos' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('../public/storage'),
        ],
```

Now I am stuck here and can't get it how to make it working. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the folder if it doesn't exist :

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $files = $request->file('file');
    $folder = public_path('../public/storage/' . Auth::id(); . '/');

    if (!Storage::exists($folder)) {
        Storage::makeDirectory($folder, 0775, true, true);
    }

    if (!empty($files)) {
        foreach($files as $file) {
            Storage::disk(['drivers' => 'local', 'root' => $folder])->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable $path is not defined, however, even if I solve this problem, there's also "Driver [] is not supported." error.

Comment: Still the same error :/ (Driver [] is not supported). Specifically this line throws an error - "throw new InvalidArgumentException("Driver [{$config['driver']}] is not supported.");"

Answer (score 1):

This is how i did it with [Image Intervention Library](http://image.intervention.io), using File instead of Storage didn't gave me an error. I am using Laravel 5.6

**Note:I am getting post id from view to controller for my scenario,then saving the post under the directory after creating a folder for the user based on user id if exists.I am also using storage_path instead of public path,you can change it according to your need**

```
use File;
use Image; //Image Intervention library

public function storeImages(Request $request,$id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);   //getting the post id from blade
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $folder = storage_path('/app/posts/' . Auth::id() . '/' . $post->id . '/');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    if (!File::exists($folder)) {
        File::makeDirectory($folder, 0775, true, true);
        $location = storage_path('/app/posts/' . Auth::id() . '/' . $post->id . '/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(800,400)->save($location); //resizing and saving the image
    }
}
```